# Want to cover up nail points in attic ceiling

Tags: attic, nails

I'm in the attic every so often to store empty boxes and I'm planning to do some wiring (non electrical) so I'm afraid that I might stand up and have nails through my head.

My plan isn't to cover the whole attic ceiling, just a small section of the attic ceiling. Any ideas on what I can do to cover the nail points?

I tried using a hammer to try to bend it but the nails are way too strong to do that.

Answer (score 10):

Leave a hardhat or bump helmet (lighter version of a hardhat) by the attic hatch. Put it on when you enter; take it off when you leave.

Comment: Yea I was thinking hard hat too

Answer (score 6):

I stick a wine cork on each nail.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using a tool called "end cutting nippers" like this one at

http://www.zoro.com/knipex-end-cutting-nippers-8-in-68-01-200/i/G4782504/?gclid=CjwKEAiAwZO0BRDvxs_1w-qFnhkSJABo10ggFX-miYd0y3GpEsBdvsvujCS5ESnbOYiu6hZYLmz5oBoChZnw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Cut the ends of the nails off close to the inside of the roof.

Comment: No, it will not cause the shingles to "take flight". A roofing job properly done means **no shiners**. The roofer was too lazy/cheap to procure the proper length nails.

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple way to cover the nail points.  Use small pieces of plastic tubing over each nail point.  Depending on the size of nails, you may need one or two different tubing sizes.  I used  "Micro-Fuel Line" from Home Depot in two sizes: 1/4" OD/7/64" ID, and 3/16" OD/3/32" ID because I had two different nail sizes in my attic.  A 10' length of each costs only $4.76.  Cut the tubing into pieces about 3/8" to 1/2" long depending on length of exposed nails in your attic, then push a piece of tubing onto each nail point.  No more nails in the head!

Answer (score 3):

Thin (1/4") plywood or OSB across the bottom of the rafters would work well. Make sure that you don't prevent air from passing under the back of the roof. As long as you leave 2 feet open at the top and bottom of the plywood, and you don't fill the roofing cavity, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue in my garage. I had the attic truss setup for storage with just enough head room to bend over and walk. Nails showing everywhere.  I think I will by some cheap long rolls of chicken wire to staple on the bottom of the roof rafters. This will keep me from causing injury to my head but will still allow air to flow under shingles

Answer (score 1):

My plan for this is to stick lattice (vinyl or Cedar) panels between the rafters. This would provide clearance over the nails, would keep airflow going, and not leave spaces for critters to hide as partial OSB coverage would. The next step up would be to cover it all with OSB with vent opening (as one would do with closed soffits) but that is probably an overkill for a storage space.

Answer (score 1):

If only a few rogues and you can get at them with Junior hacksaw then saw just under half way through near to board as possible.  Bend over with pliers or mole grips for better grip.

Add a blob of 2 part epoxy if it is still sharpish at the bend or a bit of blue tack for quickness. This is only suitable for small area as tiles now pinned tight and make them harder to remove if needed.  Best suited to a shed or a few rogues in loft.